# How to validate if a radio button is selected or not as per the HTML provided?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Here is html code for selected radio button

```
<input name="blooms_level" value="4" id="blooms_level4" class="radio " checked="" type="radio">
```

i tried below code, its returning null

```
String str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathValue")).getAttribute("checked");
            str.equalsIgnoreCase("true");
```

please suggest any alternate way since checked value is null

Comment: `@checked` is boolean attribute. You don't need to check its value, but just presence/absence

Comment: if return value is null. then it is unchecked. you check it for null instead of true. `str.equalsIgnoreCase("null")`

Comment: for checked radio button also value is null here as i given html above

Answer (score 1):

Try the Java code mentioned below:

```
Boolean radioSelected= driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathValue")).isSelected();
     if (radioSelected)
    {
      System.out.println("Radio Button is selected");
    }else{
      System.out.println("Radio Button is not selected");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate if the *radio button* is selected or not you can use either of the following solution:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='radio' and @name='blooms_level'][starts-with(@id,'blooms_level')]")).isSelected())
//if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.radio[name='blooms_level'][id^='blooms_level']")).isSelected())
    System.out.println("Radio Button is selected");
else
    System.out.println("Radio Button is not selected");
```

Comment: i want to verify whether it is selected, if not method should fail

Comment: @Ashwath To mark the method as **Fail** you need to use  _Assert_ which I think is not a part of this discussion. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: please refer my original question

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple like

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("blooms_level4")).isSelected(), "Verify checkbox is checked");
```

with [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/index.html).